# Sailsjs model afterDestroy callback seems useless, beforeDestroy not much better

Tags: sails.js

The `afterCreate` and `afterUpdate` callbacks both return the model. `afterDestroy` gives you nothing but a callback, and `beforeDestroy` only gives the criteria.

I'm curious if I'm doing it wrong....

If I use `afterDestroy` I am basically told that a 'record'....'somewhere'....was destroyed.

If I use `beforeDestroy` I then have to look the model up again myself.

I know sails aint' rails, but it makes sense to me that lifecycle callbacks would have access to the model, or if not the model, at least its values.....

What say you sails community?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Waterline v0.10.0-rc6 (released [about a month ago](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/commit/e50c5adf570922e33b9e80a1a7c81a9f2b4c94a3)) , `afterDestroy` does supply the array of destroyed instances as the first argument.  Just updated the docs, thanks for pointing it out.

As far as `beforeDestroy` is concerned, it is the same as all of the "before" callbacks, in that it gives you the criteria that will be used to find models but doesn't look them up for you.  This is to avoid unnecessary queries when you might be able to do what you need (including canceling the operation altogether) without ever hitting the database.  I'd call that very useful!

Comment: Thanks @Scott Gress, in hindsight.... The beforeDestroy makes sense. As far as rc6, clearly i need to update my package.json